# Intelij @named annotation support on a spring application

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij and Using the `@Named` annotation from the `javax` package instead of Springs `@Qualifier`.

Everything seems to work fine in runtime but Intelij seems to have a tantrum on it in the IDE itself and saying `could not autowire...`.

Any ideas how to let Intellij treat the `@Named` annotation that same as `@Qualifier`

Thanks.

Comment: At what point does the IDE say 'could not autowire'?

Comment: in the text editor, red line under the object, and the smart suggestions puts a "@named" annotation that accomplishes nothing